# python: Searching thru a router configuration for certain lines that are present

Tags: python, regex, search

I have a router configuration file.  The router has thousands of "Interfaces", and I'm trying to make sure it DOES have *two* certain lines in EACH Interface configuration section.  The typical router configuration file would look like this:

```
<whitespaces> Interface_1
<whitespaces>    description Interface_1
<whitespaces>    etc etc'
<whitespaces>    etc etc etc
<whitespaces>    <config line that i am searching to confirm is present>
<whitespaces>     etc etc etc etc
!
!
! random number of router lines 
<whitespaces>  <second config line that i am searching to confirm is     
present>
!
<whitespaces>  Interface_2
<whitespaces>     description Interface_2
<whitespaces>     etc etc
<whitespaces>     etc etc etc
<whitespaces>     <config line that I am searching to confirm is present>
<whitespaces>     etc etc etc etc
! random number of router lines
<whitespaces>    <second config line that i am searching to confirm is 
present>
etc
```

So effectively I want this logic:
- go thru the router config.  When you see Interface_X, be on the lookout for two lines AFTER that, and make sure they are present in the config.  And then move on to the next Interface, and do the same thing, over and over again.

Here is the tricky part:
-  I want the two lines to be in the Interface config, and python needs to know that the search 'area' is any line AFTER Interface_X and BEFORE the next Interface_Y config. 
-  The two lines I'm searching for are RANDOMLY spaced in the config, they aren't like the 10th line and the 12th line after Interface_X.  They can be present anywhere between Interface_X and Interface_Y (the next interface definition).

Dying.  Been on this for four days and can't seem to match it correctly.
Effectively i just want the python script to spit out output that says example:
"Interface_22 and Interface_89 are missing the two lines you are looking for Tom".  I don't care if the interface is right honestly, i really only care about  when the interface configuration is WRONG.

```
file_name = 'C:\\PYTHON\\router.txt'
f = open(file_name, 'r')
output_string_obj = f.read()
a = output_string_obj.splitlines()
    for line in a:   
        if re.match("(.*)(Interface)(.*)", line):
            #  logic to search for the presence of two lines after matching   
            #  Interface, but prior to next instance of a Interface 
            #  definition
            if re.match("(.*)(check-1-line-present)(.*)", line + ???):
                if re.match("(.*)(check-2-line-present)(.*)", line ?):
                    print ("This Interface has the appropriate config")
        else:
            print ("This Interface is missing the key two lines")
```

Dying guys.  This is the first question I've ever posted to this board.  I'll take any thoughts/logic flow / statements/ ideas anyone has.  I get in this type of search situation alot, where i don't know where in the router config something is missing, but i know it has to be somewhere between point A and point B, but have nothing else to 'grip' onto....
'''
'

Comment: How big will be your entire router configuration 1M/2M/100M? The reason I am asking is - I am wondering whether i can hold the lines in memory for 1M/2M. I might want to consider that option for 100M, that option is out of question.

Comment: You should post a real excerpt of your file.

Comment: I don't think posting a config file is an option here :-) It's a very sensitive information.

Comment: are those <whitespaces> actually  whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration file wouldn't be too big. Concept would be search in a loop thru configuration files, with the search logic, but each individual file isn't too big. Assume for this question small config file, but I see your point.

Example config would be similar to this: (ill post example tonight)

Interface_1
  Line
  Line
  Line
  ip-address x.x.x.x
  Line
  Line
  Dhcp y.y.y.y
  Line
!
!
Interface_2
  Line
  Line
  Line
  ip-address z.z.z.z
  Line
  Line
  Dhcp y.y.y.y
  Line
!
!
But its static config, where I have "Line" could be 30 lines or 10, or whatever.  But the two words I'm looking for : "ip-address" and "dhcp" with something after, are unique.

Basically I'm checking to make sure the config has both ip address and dhcp configured !

Answer (score 0):

I am giving it a shot based on information you have. Broadly the idea is as follows .

1. Define an Regex pattern that matches `^[\s]*(Interface_\d)`
2. Split the config using that string - The result is an array of strings of the following format 
   a) empty strings
   b) Interface Name
   c) Interface Config
3. Check if following patterns are matched `<config line` `<second config line`. If both match print Previous interface. Below is a complete code, you can work around it to suit your needs.

-- code

```
config = """
    Interface_1
    description Interface_1
    etc etc'
    etc etc etc
    ip-address 10.0.0.2
     etc etc etc etc
!
!
! random number of router lines
  dhcp 10.0.0.1
!
     Interface_2
     description Interface_2
     etc etc
     etc etc etc
     ip-address 10.0.0.5
     etc etc etc etc
! random number of router lines
    note: no d-hcp
"""


import re
r = re.compile(r'^[\s]*(Interface_\d+)', re.MULTILINE)
r1 = re.compile(r'ip-address')
r2 = re.compile(r'dhcp')
configs =  re.split(r, config)
for i, c in enumerate(configs):
    if r.match(c):
        continue
    if r1.search(c) and r2.search(c):
        print configs[i-1]
```

This may not be perfect, but should give you an idea about how to go about it. Agreed this is probably not the most maintainable way to write - but that's unlikely unless you can post 'real file excerpts' - which may not be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you file actually looks like but if  are actually whitespaces you can strip  and group the lines by `Interface_` with `itertools.groupby`:

```
lines = ["<second config line that i am searching to confirm is present>"
    ,"<config line that i am searching to confirm is present>"]
from itertools import groupby
with open("out.txt") as f:
    d = {}
    groups = groupby(f, lambda x: x.strip().startswith("Interface_"))
    for k, v in groups:
        if k:
            key = list(v)[0].strip()
            data = " ".join(next(groups, "  ")[1])
            d[key] = all(l in data for l in lines)

print(d)
```

Input:

```
                                  Interface_1
                                     description Interface_1
                                     etc etc'
                                     etc etc etc
                                     <config line that i am searching to confirm is present>
                                      etc etc etc etc
!
!
! random number of router lines
                                   <second config line that i am searching to confirm is present>
!
                                  Interface_2
                                      description Interface_2
                                      etc etc
                                      etc etc etc
                                      <config line that i am searching to confirm is present>
                                      etc etc etc etc
! random number of router lines
                                     <second config line that i am searching to confirm is present>
```

Output:

```
{'Interface_2': True, 'Interface_1': True}
```

Or pass a regex to groupby:

```
lines = ["<second config line that i am searching to confirm is present>"
    ,"<config line that i am searching to confirm is present>"]
from itertools import groupby
import re
with open("out.txt") as f:
    d = {}
    groups = groupby(f, lambda x: re.search("<whitespaces>\s+Interface_\d+",x))
    for k, v in groups:
        if k:
            key = list(v)[0].strip().split()[1]
            data = " ".join(next(groups, "  ")[1])
            d[key] = all(l in data for l in lines)

print(d)
```

Input:

```
<whitespaces> Interface_1
<whitespaces>    description Interface_1
<whitespaces>    etc etc'
<whitespaces>    etc etc etc
<whitespaces>    <config line that i am searching to confirm is present>
<whitespaces>     etc etc etc etc
!
!
! random number of router lines
<whitespaces>  <second config line that i am searching to confirm is present>
!
<whitespaces> Interface_2
<whitespaces>     description Interface_2
<whitespaces>     etc etc
<whitespaces>     etc etc etc
<whitespaces>     <config line that i am searching to confirm is present>
<whitespaces>     etc etc etc etc
! random number of router lines
<whitespaces>    <second config line that i am searching to confirm is present>
```

Output:

```
{'Interface_2': True, 'Interface_1': True}
```

Once you have something to pass to groupby it will split the file into sections, you can also replace the `in` search with a compiled regex search.

```
import re
regs = [re.compile("<second config line that i am searching to confirm is present>")
    ,re.compile("<config line that i am searching to confirm is present>")]
from itertools import groupby

with open("out.txt") as f:
    d = {}
    groups = groupby(f, lambda x: x.startswith("<whitespaces> Interface_"))
    for k, v in groups:
        if k:
            key = list(v)[0].strip().split()[1]
            data = " ".join(next(groups, "  ")[1])
            d[key] = all(reg.search(data) for reg in regs)
```

If you were sure the lines were always `<whitespaces>` a single space followed by `Interface_` you can use that as the delimiter:

```
groups = groupby(f, lambda x: x.startswith("<whitespaces> Interface_"))
```

This won't read all the data into memory at once so if you have millions of lines it will be effcient.

Answer (score 0):

Read your file into a list of lines.

```
with open('C:\\PYTHON\\router.txt') as config:
    lines = config.readlines()
```

Strip the whitespace.

```
lines = [ln.strip() for ln in lines]
```

Get the indices of the interface lines in a dictionary by interface name.

```
interfaces = {name: num for num, name in enumerate(lines)
              if name.startswith('Interface_')}
```

Check that the lines you want exist.

```
for name in interfaces.keys():
   idx = interfaces[name]+2  # Shouldn't this be 3 to skip the description?
   if not 'config item string' in lines[idx]:
       print name, 'does not have the right config!'
```